# Java method scope issue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, compiler-construction, scope

I have two distinct archives within in the same .ear deployed on an application server. One is a .war and one is a .jar. I have the same package names in both archives

```
in .jar archive>> com.me.dummy.MyClass
in .war archive>> com.me.dummy.CLientClass
```

In `com.me.dummy.MyClass` I have a protected method called `proctectedMethod()` . In `com.me.dummy.CLientClass` i invoke `com.me.dummy.MyClass.proctectedMethod()`.

This does not cause any compile time issues, but at runtime it throws accessError

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError
```

Why does this only throw the `IllegalAccessError` at runtime?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this happens because your application server loads web application using separate class loader. You should consult your app server documentation how to make it to use the same class loader for whole enterprise application.